# Unify lines that contains same patterns

Tags: regex, sed

I have a database with this structure:

```
word1#element1.1#element1.2#element1.3#...
word2#element2.1#element2.2#element2.3#...
...
...
```

I would like to unify the elements of 2 or more lines every time the word at the beginning is the same.
Example:

```
...
word8#element8.1#element8.2#element8.3#...
word9#element9.1#element9.2#element9.3#...
...
```

Now, lets suppose word8=word9, this is the result:

```
...
word8#element8.1#element8.2#element8.3#...#element9.1#element9.2#element9.3#...
...
```

I tried with the command `sed`:

- I match 2 lines at time with `N`
- Memorize the first word of the first line: `^\([^#]*\)` (all the elements exept '#')
- Memorize all the other elements of the first line: `\([^\n]*\)`
- Check if in the second line (after `\n`) is present the same word: `\1`
- If it's like that I just take out the newline char and the first word of the second line: `\1#\2`

This is the complete code:

```
sed 'N;s/^\([^#]*\)#\([^\n]*\)\n\1/\1#\2/' database
```

I would like to understand why it's not working and how I can solve that problem.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: not `[#]*` it's `[^#]*`

Comment: sorry, error typing...

Comment: you should tell if your file was sorted by 1st field (word 1,2....), if not sorted, what do you want to do the "join"?

Comment: yes, the file is sorted by 1st field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/^\(\([^#]*#\).*\)\n\2/\1#/;P;D' file
```

Read 2 lines at all times and remove the line feed and the matching portion of the second line (reinstating the `#`) if the words at the beginning of those 2 lines match.

Comment: the solution is beautiful but I thing it fails if we have 3 or more lines with a common key.

Comment: @JJoao To handle more than 2 lines use. `sed ':a;N;s/^\(\([^#]*#\).*\)\n\2/\1#/;ta;P;D' file`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '#n
H
$ { x
:cycle
  s/\(\n\)\([^#]*#\)\([^[:cntrl:]]*\)\1\2/\1\2\3#/g
  t cycle
  s/.//
  p
  }' YourFile
```

Assuming word are sorted

- load the whole file in buffer (code could be adapted if file is to big to use only several lines in buffer)
- at the end, load holding buffer content to working buffer
- remove the new line and first word of any line where previous line start with same word (and add a `#` as seprator)
- if occur, retry once again
- if not, remove first char (a new line due to loading process)
- print

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). It reads input file line by line, splits in first `#` character and uses a `hash` of `arrays` to save the first word as key and append the rest of the line as value. At the `END` block it sorts by the first word and joins the lines:

```
perl -lne '
    ($key, $line) = split /#/, $_, 2;
    push @{$hash{$key}}, $line;
    END { 
        for $k ( sort keys %hash ) { 
            printf qq|%s#%s\n|, $k, join q|#|, @{$hash{$k}};
        }   
    }   
' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Using text replacements:

```
perl -p0E 'while( s/(^|\n)(.+?#)(.*)\n\2(.*)/$1$2$3 $4/ ){}' yourfile
```

or indented:

```
perl -p0E 'while(           # while we can 
      s/(^|\n)                # substitute \n
        (.+?\#)    (.*)  \n     #    id  elems1
         \2        (.*)         #    id  elems2
       /$1$2$3 $4/x             # \n id  elems1 elems2
    ){}'
```

thanks: @birei

Comment: I would mark first newline character optional, because otherwise it wouldn't match same pattern between first and second lines. Although it will leave a blank one at the beginning, but it does not seem critical.

Comment: @Birei, thank you for the bug report and suggestion. I edited  in similar  way: `s/(^|\n) ... /$1../` in order to remove the blank.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
word1#element1.1#element1.2#element1.3
word2#element2.1#element2.2#element2.3
word8#element8.1#element8.2#element8.3
word8#element9.1#element9.2#element9.3
word9#element9.1#element9.2#element9.3
```

.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="#"}
    NR>1 && $1!=prev { print "" }
    $1==prev { sub(/^[^#]+/,"") }
    { printf "%s",$0; prev=$1 }
    END { print "" }
' file
word1#element1.1#element1.2#element1.3
word2#element2.1#element2.2#element2.3
word8#element8.1#element8.2#element8.3#element9.1#element9.2#element9.3
word9#element9.1#element9.2#element9.3
```